# When I hover a menu item it affect other items. All other elements moving. How to stop other elements to move from position

Tags: html, css, hover

When I hover a menu item it affect other items. All other elements are moving. How to stop other elements to move from its position. Someone please review my code. I want the menu item to be bold when I hover and all the menu item does not move to its position. I tried many different ways to but it always moves and changing other elements positions

Here is the code:

````
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
</head>



<style>

    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style: none;
        font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    }

    .container {
        background-color: #242633;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    .row {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }

    .logo img {
        margin-left: 50px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-right: 150px;
        height: auto;
        width: 120px;
    }

    .menu {
        position: relative;

    }

    .menu ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        color: #fff;
        margin-inline: 50px;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 25px;
        transition: all 0.5s;
    }

    .list {
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid red;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        z-index: 10;
    }

    .menu ul li:hover {
        color: #c5c5c5;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: transparent;
        font-weight: 900;
        z-index: 50;

    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="./Images/logo.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="list active">Home</li>
                    <li>Streets</li>
                    <li>Merchandise</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you increase the font-weight on hover, you are in turn increasing the size of the text in the `<li>` and if the `<li>` doesn't already have enough space to contain the text, it needs to adapt its width and this ends up pushing the other elements.

You can simply increase the width of `<li>` so that the contained text can safely scale within the increased container without altering any of the surrounding elements, like so:

````html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Portfolio</title>
  </head>

  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      text-decoration: none;
      list-style: none;
      font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    }

    .container {
      background-color: #242633;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .row {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: flex-start;
    }

    .logo img {
      margin-left: 50px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-right: 150px;
      height: auto;
      width: 120px;
    }

    .menu {
      position: relative;
    }

    .menu ul {
      display: flex;
      gap: 50px;
    }

    .menu ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      color: #fff;
      width: 150px;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 25px;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }

    .list {
      position: relative;
      border: 1px solid red;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    .menu ul li:hover {
      color: #c5c5c5;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: transparent;
      font-weight: 900;
      z-index: 50;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="./Images/logo.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
          <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Streets</li>
            <li>Merchandise</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```
````

Comment: https://codedamn.com/playground/fe5-VXD7zE9RRXehaTzIa. Thank you for the reply. Can you please see the code. Its still not working

Comment: @Change you have changed the code to increase the font-size as well and because of that you can see the text is being altered vertically. To fix that you need to increase the height of the `<li>` to adapt.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. I changed the height an width. It working. Great bro

Comment: Great. Can you indicate you have accepted this answer by clicking the tick icon?